# cómo hacer el formato geojson con lineString

Tags: java, json, spring, geojson

Disculpen, tengo una pregunta que pojo deberia hacer para que me traiga line y points a la misma vez.

La idea que tengo es que no quisiera usar otro pojo mas mas que solo buscar una solucion ya que me saleen los puntos pero no los `lineString`

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "LineString"
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  -87.72158863628451,
                  41.88857748226596
                ],
                [
                  -87.71467926585602,
                  41.88753117344939
                ]
              ],
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.415061, 40.506229]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.505184, 40.488084]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-121.354465, 40.488737]
            }
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que el json que has puesto no es correcto. Puedes intentar validarlo en https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ y verás los errores que tiene.

He corregido un par de errores, tal y cómo yo considero que estaría bien. Esto tendrías que revisarlo. El archivo quedaría así:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              -87.72158863628451,
              41.88857748226596
            ],
            [
              -87.71467926585602,
              41.88753117344939
            ]
          ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.415061, 40.506229]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.505184, 40.488084]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-121.354465, 40.488737]
        }
    }]
}
```

Para generar ver el POJO correspondiente puedes usar una herramienta de este estilo http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, que te genera el POJO:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"type",
"features"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
@JsonProperty("features")
private List<Feature> features = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("type")
public String getType() {
return type;
}

@JsonProperty("type")
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

@JsonProperty("features")
public List<Feature> getFeatures() {
return features;
}

@JsonProperty("features")
public void setFeatures(List<Feature> features) {
this.features = features;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Feature.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"type",
"geometry"
})
public class Feature {

@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
@JsonProperty("geometry")
private Geometry geometry;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("type")
public String getType() {
return type;
}

@JsonProperty("type")
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

@JsonProperty("geometry")
public Geometry getGeometry() {
return geometry;
}

@JsonProperty("geometry")
public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
this.geometry = geometry;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Geometry.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"type",
"coordinates"
})
public class Geometry {

@JsonProperty("type")
private String type;
@JsonProperty("coordinates")
private List<List<Double>> coordinates = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("type")
public String getType() {
return type;
}

@JsonProperty("type")
public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

@JsonProperty("coordinates")
public List<List<Double>> getCoordinates() {
return coordinates;
}

@JsonProperty("coordinates")
public void setCoordinates(List<List<Double>> coordinates) {
this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Espero que te solucione el problema.